# incorrect number of table entries using LuaXml

Tags: xml-parsing, lua, lua-table

I'm using LuaXml to convert a xml string received from network to Lua table but got two problems. Anyone could help to point out the problem? Thanks!

1) **xml.eval** returns a table with 4 entries instead of 3. My intention is to get 3 entries of "preset", but got 4 entries with the last one showing "**presets**" .

2) I was hoping to use **tbl.find**("preset") to get the 3 entries of "preset" before the **for** loop and get attributes of each entry, but **tbl.find**("preset") would return nil.

Here is the code.

```
xml = require("LuaXml")
buff = "\
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?> \
<presets> \
<preset name=\"preset1\" url=\"Load?name=testlist1\" id=\"1\"/> \
<preset name=\"preset2\" url=\"Load?name=testlist2\" id=\"2\"/> \
<preset name=\"preset3\" url=\"Load?name=testlist3\" id=\"3\"/> \
</presets>"

local tbl = xml.eval(buff)
for i in pairs(tbl) do
    print("name: " .. tbl[i].name .. ", id: " .. tbl[i].id .. ", url: " .. tbl[i].url)
end
```

Comment: Does `luaxml` need those quotes escaped or does `lua` since you are using double quotes to enclose the string? If you quote the string using single quotes or lua long string (`[[...]]`) syntax I would imagine you don't need to escape those quotes.

Comment: What's the output to your code?

Comment: @Etan  the double quotation mark problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: And, if you use `for k, v in pairs(tbl) do`, you can `printf("name: %s, id: %s, url: %s", v.name, v.id, v.url)` (prtinf is defined as: `function printf(s, ...) return s:format(...) end`

Comment: @Advert Thanks for the comment, I didn't understand *pairs* function. The goal is to retrieve each preset entry and put the attributes into a Lua table. The code above only does the print though. But I don't know why *xml.eval* returns 4 entries

Comment: @Advert  I tried printf but got this error *"attempt to call global 'printf' (a nil value)"*. I googled but didn't find solution.

Comment: Add this somewhere near the top of your code (you can make it local if you don't want to mess with globals): `function printf(s, ...) return s:format(...) end`. It's not in standard Lua (hence why you have to define it), but it's in other languages like C. The error you're getting means that `printf` is of type `nil`, which means it hasn't been defined.

Comment: @Advert Thank you. I thought printf was standard Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of experimental poking suggests that `LuaXml` creates an entry in the table for the toplevel xml document element (at index `0`) and then an additional element for each direct child tag of that element (at sequential numerical indices).

So your output table is:

```
> for i=0,#tbl do print(i, type(tbl[i]), tbl[i]) end
0       string  presets
1       table   <preset url="Load?name=testlist1" name="preset1" id="1" />

2       table   <preset url="Load?name=testlist2" name="preset2" id="2" />

3       table   <preset url="Load?name=testlist3" name="preset3" id="3" />
```

This strikes me as a very odd way of handling things but that seems to be what it does.